# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string when count(*) is used

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm getting below error when i execute the given query. The same query returns result when i replace count(*) with * but still scrolling through the result set gives me the same error again. Please help resolving this.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM cd_table
WHERE
     SW_CODE = 'PSTN' AND
     CRP_CODE = 'WLR' AND
     ERR_CODE = nvl('',  ERR_CODE)  AND
     PRS_ID = 'E' AND
     STATUS in ('0', '1')  and
     TO_DATE(TRANS_ST_DATE,'DD/MM/YY') > sysdate-90 ;
```

The value in TRANS_ST_DATE is a varchar and the data looks like 23/09/14.

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Comment: change: ERR_CODE = nvl('',  ERR_CODE)  AND  to: ERR_CODE IS NULL AND

Comment: It works fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38317 You likely to have not what you think in `TRANS_ST_DATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, promise not to store data as strings in the future.  SQL has native types for date/times.  Use them.

Clearly, the format of the column is not what you expect.  You can try this:

```
(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(TRANS_ST_DATE, 1, 2) BETWEEN '01' and '31' and
           SUBSTR(TRANS_ST_DATE, 4, 2) BETWEEN '01' and '12' AND
           TRANS_ST_DATE LIKE '__/__/__'
      THEN TO_DATE(TRANS_ST_DATE,'DD/MM/YY')
 END) > sysdate - 90
```

You can find the offending values with something like:

```
select TRANS_ST_DATE
from cd_table
where (NOT SUBSTR(TRANS_ST_DATE, 1, 2) BETWEEN '01' and '31') OR
      (NOT SUBSTR(TRANS_ST_DATE, 4, 2) BETWEEN '01' and '12') OR
      (TRANS_ST_DATE NOT LIKE '__/__/__')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... It helped me find the offending values and have corrected them. This table I'm dealing with is a 3rd party's. I swear i didnot/will not do the same mistake.. ha ha ha. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a front end client like SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer, these clients return only a few rows say first 50 or 500 rows when you do `select * from table`. Hence your query is returning results while doing `select * from table`

Coming to the issue that you are facing, it usually comes when the ate cannot be converted to the desired format. So you need to check what is there in the `TRANS_ST_DATE` column.

Lastly modify the NVL clause as @jim mcnamara has suggested in his comment as the way you are using it is not logically correct

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: thanks bro... u got me right. Its sql developer. There are 25 rows of type '20110818' where million rows have values as '18/08/11'.